# Connecting to Mongodb Database from Power BI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, redhat

We have Mongodb has database, hosted with Redhat servers.
Our clients need access to our database via Power BI, we have shared IP address database username, password and port number. But still they are not able access the database.

We need to know that is it possible to connect the Mongodb with Power BI permanently or is there other way that we need to fallow.

Comment: do you have webapi for mongodb? can you access webapi, if yes you could connect to webapi in powerbi.

Comment: No we don't have any Web api's. Will it not be possible to connect  to Power BI without webapi